# Microsoft Graph Api List ownedObjects - applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-ownedobjects?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=cs

---

- Azure AD: user-A owns group-A
- Azure AD: user-A owns application-A

---

- the user-list-ownedobjects returns group-A
- the user-list-ownedobjects does not return application-A

---

Is this the expected behaviour? Am I missing something... If so, is there a query to get the application owned by user-A?

Regards,
Florian

Comment: I suppose you use the `v1.0`, just use the `beta` version instead of `v1.0`, it will work. sample : `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/{id | userPrincipalName}/ownedObjects`.

Comment: I think @JoyWang is right. I did a quick test using Microsoft Graph Explorer and beta endpoint does work fine.. I would also add that if it's production application related code, then using beta endpoint APIs is not recommended or supported, you may need to look at older Azure AD Graph API `https://graph.windows.net`

Comment: v1.0 doesn't really have application resource type or any of the related APIs, it's only available in beta (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-beta), and that's probably why you won't get back application type objects back when using the ownedObjects API with Microsoft Graph v1.0 endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you use the `v1.0`, just use the `beta` version instead of `v1.0`, it will work.

**Sample** :

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/ownedObjects`.

Also, as @Rohit Saigal mentioned, the application resource type is only available in beta version, and  don't recommend you to use `beta` version in production environment. You may could use AAD Graph instead of it, it also works.

`GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/ownedObjects`.